# RecordContext differs between WithRecord and TextField components

Tags: reactjs, react-context, react-admin

I have a (simplified) component that uses react-admin that looks like this:

```js
import { RecordContextProvider, WithRecord } from 'ra-core'
import { TextField } from 'react-admin'

const ModalComponent = () => {
  ...
  return (
    <RecordContextProvider value={{id: 'different-id-than-parent'}}>
          <WithRecord render={(record) => <>{record.id}</>} />
          <TextField source="id" />
    </RecordContextProvider>
  )
}
```

Now, this `ModalComponent` already has a `RecordContext` when being called, but it's a different one that I want.

The problem: When I render the `ModalComponent` the values of the `WithRecord` component and the `TextField` component vary, even if they access the exact same source. i.e. `WithRecord` prints "different-id-than-parent" and `TextField` prints "id-from-parent".

How can that even be the case? Shouldn't the `RecordContext` be the same for both child components?

I can't replicate this behavior in a sandbox.